# Tree root finding

Tags: algorithm, tree, computer-science, graph-algorithm

How could I get from set of nodes and edges get tree with a root?
(I'm working with connectivity-matrix, each edge has weight: graph[i][j], without any negative edges). Later I need to do DFS and find LCA's in that tree, so it would be good for optimize.

Comment: I take it this is a directed graph? Otherwise, any node in a tree would be a valid root.

Comment: Yes, graph is directed, the task is to change orientation(?)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your matrix represents the child relationship (i.e. `M[i][j]` tells that `j` is the child of `i`), for a [directed graph G(V,E)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

You have 2 different strategies:

- use a bit vector, go through each cell of your matrix, and mark the child index in the vector if the cell's weight is not null): the root is the vertex not set in the vector,
- look for the columns (or rows, if your matrix is column first) whose cells are all null (no ancestors),

The second solution is better for dense matrices. Its worst running time would be when the root is the last entry (O(V²)). In this case you can stop at the first hit, or run til the end to get all the roots, if your graph has many.

The first one is better suited for sparse matrices, since you have to go through all the cells. It's running time is in O(E). You also get all the roots with this algorithm.

If you are certain that your graph has only one root, you can use the walk the edges up technique, as described in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a computationally MUCH SLOWER version that is also much easier to code.  For small graphs, it is just fine.

Find the node with in-degree zero!

You have to compute all node degrees, O(n), but depending on the setting, this is often much easier to code and thus less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one node in the tree and walk up, that is, against the orientation of the edges. When you find a node without an ancestor you have the root.

If you need to do something like this often, just remember the parent node for each node.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP's graph is a tree, I think he has a graph, and he needs to find a spanning tree. In a clique for instance, the algorithm will never end (or fail if you keep a set of visited nodes), but there is definetly a spanning tree in it.

Comment: The question is about “tree root finding”, so that's what I was answering. Obviously, if the OP doesn't have a tree, then he has to specify what does he have and what exactly does he want to find.

Comment: The solution for me was: make symmetric connectivity-matrix, do DFS for any node(node 0 for example), then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

a DFS search from any graph gives you a tree (assuming the graph is connected, of course).

you can iterate it, and start from each node as a possible root, you will get a spanning tree eventually this way, if there is one. complexity will be O(V^2+VE)

**EDIT:** it works because for any finite graph, if there is a root form node a to node b, there will be a path from a to b in the tree DFS creates. so, assuming there is a possible spanning tree, there is a root r, which you can get from to each v in V. when iterating when r chosen as root, there is a path from r to each v in V, so there will be a path from r to it in the spanning tree.

Comment: Okay, situation: two nodes connected to one. Graph is directed, doing DFS from the central node will do nothing(directed connections)

Comment: @scrat: iterate it for every node as possible root, you will eventually find a legal spanning tree if there is one.

Comment: @scrat: look at the edit, added a small explanation why it works, proving it formally should be easy following this guidelines (if needed).

Comment: But for doing it I'll need symmetric connectivity matrix? Example list of Source-node Destination-node and Edge-weight: http://pastebin.com/cQP9PEpm
There is simply no root!

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding you, why is (1) not a root? there is 1->2,2->3 path, so (1) is a root, there is a path (1->2) to (2) and a path (1->2->3) to (3) on the DFS spanning tree. and you will not need symetric connectivity matrix, every edge which is not in the list can implicitly be non existing.

Comment: it's not matrix, it's list of (Source node, Dest. node, Weight)